# Crawl specific Content Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, crawling

I have three content databases in the same Web App, and I want to create a separate Content Source to crawl one of the content databases on a different schedule from the others.  Can this be done on a SharePoint 2013 farm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution for this scenarios is to provide the site collection url's of specific content database in multiple content sources for crawling in different schedules. but you need to make sure that those site collection url's were created based on different content databases.

**The main need for site collection url's is because in SharePoint the crawling is mainly based on content source url's but not based on content databases.**

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try. Only issue is for Crawl Settings, select Crawl everything... or Only crawl the Site Collection... when creating separate Content Sources?

Comment: yes, thats the way how it works.

Comment: Sorry, what I was asking is which do I choose for each Content Source?  Thanks

Comment: mention the site collection url's. but as i mentioned, you need to know which site collection is mapped to which content databases for specific crawl schedules. you may also refer : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105150/how-can-i-know-in-which-content-database-my-site-collection-is-stored