# How to check the 'AllDocs' count for specific site collection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We are running Gradual delete timer job on large site collection and want to trace the progress of this job on content deletion.

So, I wanted to check the rows count on  'AllDocs'  table for a particular site collection, so that i can compare the table data count with before and after gradual delete job started.

How to check this in SQL on that site content database?

Answer (score 2):

Doing anything in SQL on SharePoint databases, sans the Usage database, is not supported.

That said, the query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM AllDocs (NoLock) WHERE SiteId = '<SiteCollectionId>'
```

[Support for changes to the databases that are used by Office server products and by Windows SharePoint Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr)

Comment: thank you. can we run the queries which are read only outputs from database without any update queries

Comment: You shouldn't be. Treat SharePoint databases as black boxes. Instead use the proper APIs in SharePoint to accomplish what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few links which might be helpful for you

[PowerShell Script to List the documents checked out with version details in a Site Collection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12966.sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-list-the-documents-checked-out-with-version-details-in-a-site-collection.aspx)

[Know in which content database my site collection is stored](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105150/how-can-i-know-in-which-content-database-my-site-collection-is-stored)